# Arduino compiler can't find implemented methods in C library

Tags: c, arduino

I wrote my own library for an Arduino Leonardo. It consists of some header files and all defined methods are implemented in *.c-files. When I compile it with Eclipse everything works fine, but the compiler of the Arduino IDE doesn't get the methods. It returns the error messages:

```
impl.cpp:20: undefined reference to initOptiCom()
impl.cpp:21: undefined reference to calc(unsigned char*, int)
impl.cpp:25: undefined reference to getInitSeq(unsigned char*, long*, long)
impl.cpp:32: undefined reference to decode(unsigned char*, long)
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

All files can be found in the arduino library dir and all libraries are included...
I searched for some examples that implement a C-library for arduino but I found just some for C++.

Maybe you know what's wrong here, I tried a lot but failed :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it's just name mangling. Either declare the functions as `extern "C"`, or compile them as C++ (rename the file to `.cpp` or pass the `-x c++` flag to GCC when compiling).

Comment: That was fast, thank you! 
I added
    '#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C"{
    #endif


    #ifdef __cplusplus
    } // extern "C"
    #endif'
around it and now it works :-)